# Scraping Javascript generated content in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'd like to get the data from this page https://widgets1.fxpro.com/Home/CurrencyMovers, basically getting plain text content TRY 0.33%, GOLD 0.26%,... What's the esiest way to do that using PHP based software or some  web based service? I have tried to study the source code, but was unable to get the data source directly. Therefor I'll need to use something like a headless browser.

Comment: Why not to use `curl` to to fetch the content? And then parse the html with pure DOM functions or a third party library like simplehtmldom

Comment: @Athafoud page use `javascript` and probably `web sockets` to get data from server.

Comment: May phantomjs do the trick then

Comment: yes, something like phantomjs can do that, I just need it to be running on a shared hosting, therefor PHP based software or 3rd party service would be the best

Comment: You can try to use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221571/python-scrapy-dynamic-web-sites/21223620#21223620) to read the dynamically generated contents. But it is using Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's probably impossible to do that on a shared hosting, fortunately my provider installed PhantomJS on request, so it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data probably are get from server by javascript using `web socket` so normal tools can't handled this - maybe with `headless browser` like `Selenium` you could get that data.