# Page content not in response to get request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to access my transaction history from my online banking page using python and requests.  I have no trouble logging on with requests and getting my account overview page content but the bank account transaction data is not in the response text. Obviously, it shows up in my browser when I access the same page.

Viewing the raw html through my browser, my bank transaction data is present; however, it is not present in the response content I receive from a get request in python.

I'm thinking this has something to do with the following: 
When the page is accessed through a browser, the transaction data is temporarily not visible because it is being loaded by some unknown background process. I think that the same process is happening when I access the site via python but the request response only contains the content that is present during the initial state of page when accessed; this state does not include the transaction data because the data is still loading.

One thing that supports this theory is the fact that the response text received through python and the response text in the browser (when viewed in developer tools) are identical until this line in the html:

```
<div id="accountRefreshDiv" style="display:none"><img blah blah>Updating...</div>
```

"Updating" also appears in the browser, along with a little spiny wheel, when the page is  first accessed.

So my question is, what type of sub process could be going on in the background and how do I go about fetching the data that it is fetching (probably with JavaScript) but with python?

Comment: Please clarify *"Viewing the raw html through my browser*". Did you do `View source` or inspect the DOM with something like Firebug? Most likely the content is loaded via an AJAX request, and there's no way to accomplish this with the `requests` library - `requests` only does HTTP. You'd need to use something like Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: Are you looking at the **raw** content in your browser or in the **DOM representation**. There is a big difference between the two. *View Source* gives you the former, looking in the developer tools (with *inspect element* and such) the latter.

Comment: @LukasGraf: requests can *load the AJAX request* though. You cannot execute the JavaScript that triggers the request. You need to be more precise there. :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221571/python-scrapy-dynamic-web-sites/21223620

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough - I guess I should rephrase that ;-). This can't be accomplished in a way where `requests` automatically does all the work for you, like a browser does. You'd need to manually have it create that AJAX request with the correct parameters.

Comment: Yes; when I said "Viewing the raw html through my browser" I meant viewing the source as well as viewing the DOM; I have been doing both. I'm not real familiar with ajax, but I figured it had something to do my current roadblock.