# How to scrape data in an authenticated session within a dynamic page?

Tags: authentication, xpath, scrapy, scrape

I have coded a Scrapy spider using the loginform library (http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2012/10/26/filling-login-forms-automatically/) and taking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221571/python-scrapy-dynamic-web-sites) as reference for dynamic webpages. This is the code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    login_user = 'myusername'
    login_pass = 'mypassword'

    name = "tv"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ["https://twitter.com/Acrocephalus/followers"]
    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('https://twitter\.com/.*')), callback='parse_items', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        args, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body, self.login_user, self.login_pass)
        return FormRequest(url, method=method, formdata=args, callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self, response):
# you are logged in here 
        
        def __init__(self):
            CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
# use any browser you wish
            self.browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
    
        def __del__(self):
            self.browser.close()
        
        def parse_item(self, response):
            item = TwitterVizItem() 
            self.browser.get(response.url)
            # let JavaScript Load
            time.sleep(3) 

# scrape dynamically generated HTML
            hxs = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source) 
            item['Follower'] = hxs.select('(//span[@class="u-linkComplex-target"])[position()>2]').extract()
            item['Follows'] = hxs.select('(//span[@class="u-linkComplex-target"])[position()=1]').extract()
            return item
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1.post1+g5b8c9e5 started (bot: TwitterViz)
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'TwitterViz.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['TwitterViz.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'TwitterViz'}
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-07-22 18:46:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-07-22 18:46:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FAcrocephalus%2Ffollowers> from <GET https://twitter.com/Acrocephalus/followers>
2015-07-22 18:46:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FAcrocephalus%2Ffollowers> (referer: None)
2015-07-22 18:46:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://twitter.com/Acrocephalus/followers> from <POST https://twitter.com/sessions>
2015-07-22 18:46:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://twitter.com/Acrocephalus/followers> (referer: https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FAcrocephalus%2Ffollowers)
2015-07-22 18:46:40 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-07-22 18:46:40 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2506,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 63188,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 46, 40, 538785),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 16, 46, 38, 926487)}
2015-07-22 18:46:40 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

From the ouput I understand that it logs in properly. However, it doesn't **scrape** anything. I've tested the XPath with Firefox's XPath Checker and they seem to work properly. Can anyone have a look to see if we can find what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to scrape Twitter. People usually scrape a website for a couple of reasons. One is that the website they are trying to scrape does not have an API and therefore the only way to extract data from it is to scrape it. The other reason is that the website does provide an API but it may lack some features or it might restrict the number of calls you can make to it. Twitter has an API and I don't think it is very restrictive. May I ask why you want to scrape twitter?

Comment: `I've tested the XPath with Firefox's XPath Checker and they seem to work properly.` Can you test it again with the code itself (not inside Firefox), using something like `scrapy shell` or `pdb`? That's because some sites may detect non-human access and may give responses like a warning, a captcha, a non-200 HTTP status, or simply empty responses. Please first make sure that Twitter provided the same or similar content as you visit it using a browser. Also I agree with @arnm that the Twitter API could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The problem with the Twitter API is that it has a limit of 180  requests per 15 minutes, taking a long time to scrape just a single account.

Comment: Ok, it is against their ToS so if this is for anything other than a pet project I would recommend against it.

Comment: It's not a pet project. What would you recommend arnm?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your use case so I'm not sure what to recommend. Maybe try to optimize your calls as much as possible? Maybe you can get the information you need from one endpoint from a completely different endpoint and thus not reaching a limit as quickly. Try to make the most of each call: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

Comment: Thanks arnm, I'll think about it.