# How to select all URLs in a web site excluding those of a given class?

Tags: python, regex, xpath

I would like to select all the URLs from my Twitter followers page using regex. If I use `https://twitter\.com/.*` it will select all the URLs matching this pattern in the website, but I'd like to exclude users on the Who To Follow section. This URLs are within the WhoToFollow class. So, my question is: can I use XPath, regex or a combination of both to select all URLs matching the previous pattern but excluding the URLs within the WhoToFollow class in Python?
Thanks!

Dani

Comment: Could you please provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. I don't know how to provide an MVCE in this case. I haven't coded anything yet, just thinking how can I achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i correctly understood, you can use such xpath, taking `a tag` not with class `WhoToFollow` and having url beginning with `https://twitter.com/`. Then it takes content of href

```
//a[not(@class="WhoToFollow") and starts-with(@href, "https://twitter.com/")]/@href
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Comment: Are you familiar with scrapy? Maybe you could have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568395/how-to-scrap-data-in-an-authenticated-sesion-within-a-dynamic-page

Comment: No problem! I appreciate your help. Cheers!